# Java Eclipse - I don't see "Android Application" when I select File/New

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Trying to brush the dust off of my Java skills and installed the Android SDK, JDK(x64) and Eclipse(x64) and thought I'd start slow with an Android "Hello, world" app.

I followed the tutorials [here](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-setup-android-development_23.html) and [here](http://www.android-app-market.com/android-development-environment-setup.html)

I am able to configure and open the android virtual device manager, but when I goto File and New, I don't see "Android Application" as an option.  Is there a setting I've missed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, really?  I get down voted without the courtesy of a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File --> New --> Other --> Under wizard type Android, You will see Android application there.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that "Android Project" = "Android Application"?

Comment: Better way to go, Open package explorer, right click you will see, New --> Android application

Comment: Man has this changed from the last time I used it - I feel old. ;)

Answer (score 1):

if You cant find it in new move down the options where you can see others and there you can find it.

Comment: in new go to others under that you can find android applications